# consistency check across files

Tags: python, sed, awk, grep

I have a few comma delmited files in a folder. The lines look like this...

```
1,2,3,4,5
6,7,8
9,10
11,12,13,14,15
```

All the files are expected to have exact 5 columns. But there are a few files where one or all the lines are less than 5 as shown above.
How do I know the names of such files?

If all the lines have exactly 4 comma then there is no issue and such files are considered OK.

Comment: The files are gzipped. Is there any way to query the data without unzipping them first?

Comment: gunzip -c $file | awk -F, 'NF!=5{print '"$file"' $0}' Put it in a for loop. good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

does this line (find + awk) work for you?

```
 find . -name *.txt |xargs -I{} awk -F',' 'NF!=5{print FILENAME;exit;}' {}
```

assume that  your files have extension "txt"

**update**

OP wants the line numbers:

```
kent$  head *.txt
==> 4.txt <==
1,2,3,4,5
6,7,8
9,10
11,12,13,14,15

==> one.txt <==
1,2,3,4,5
6,7,8
9,10
11,12,13,14,15

==> three.txt <==
11,12,13,14,15

==> two.txt <==
11,12,13,14,15

kent$  find . -name *.txt |xargs -I{} awk -F',' 'NF!=5{print FILENAME,NR}' {}
./one.txt 2
./one.txt 3
./4.txt 2
./4.txt 3
```

**update again**

OP, you should describe your question more clearly.

so you want the total line numbers (the sum):

```
kent$  find . -name *.txt |xargs -I{} awk -F',' 'NF!=5{a[FILENAME]++;} END{if(a[FILENAME]) print FILENAME, a[FILENAME]}' {}
./one.txt 2
./4.txt 2
```

Comment: I have found the file that does not follow the rule. But how do I know the line where the problem is?

Comment: do you need "all" invalid line numbers? or the first invalid line number per file?

Comment: all invalid lines in that file

Comment: Thanks for the update. What I really wanted to know is the total number of invalid lines, not line numbers. # awk -F'^' 'NF!=22{print $0;}' | wc -l # does not work

Comment: Correct. I did not ask before because I did not think it was possible!

Answer (score 1):

Something like (**NB this checks there are 5 columns - not that there are 4 `,`'s**):

```
import gzip
from glob import iglob
import csv

for filename in iglob('*.gz'): # or get filenames from wherever
    with gzip.open(filename) as fin:
        if not all(len(row) == 5 for row in csv.reader(fin)):
            print filename
```

Comment: AttributeError: GzipFile instance has no attribute '__exit__' # Python 2.6.8

Comment: @shantanuo `with` support wasn't added until 2.7 - so, prior to that, yes it would need re-writing slightly

Answer (score 0):

In Python:

```
def fileIsGood(filename):
    for line in open(filename):
        if len(line.split(",")) != 5:
            return False
    return True

fileNames = ["foo.txt", "bar.bat", "baz.exe"]
for fileName in fileNames:
    if not fileIsGood(fileName):
        print fileName
```

Comment: This is working as expected. But I am not able to collect filenames programmatically. I do also need to unzip before opening the file.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `count` to count the `','` on each line:

```
import gzip
def is_good(fname):
    with gzip.open(fname,'r') as f:
        return all( line.count(',') == 4 for line in f )

#somehow get filenames.  Here I'll assume glob
good_files = [ fname for fname in glob.glob('*.gz') if is_good(fname) ]
# or if you like functional programming:
#good_files = filter(is_good, glob.glob('*.gz'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

def check_file(name):
    with open(name, 'r') as f:
        while line = f.readline():
            if line.count(',') != 4:
                return False
    return True

def check(path):
    return [filename for filename in os.listdir(path) if not check_file(filename)]
```

Answer (score 0):

This extended grep command should work:

```
grep -vEl '^[^,]+(,[^,]+){4}$'
```

If the files gzipped you can use zgrep:

```
zgrep -vEl '^[^,]+(,[^,]+){4}$'
```